# WCF Storm is it still live?

Tags: wcf, wcfstorm

I was using SoapUI to test a WCF endpoint (unsuccessfully I am add) which has message based security using an X509 certificate.

After much head scratching and searching I discovered that SoapUI does not like X509, message, wsHttpBinding and came across WCF Storm.

This works out of the box, but my concern is that nothing appears to have moved on  the project since 2015.

Is this still a dead project now?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Never mind that this is out of scope. The latest version is 3.4.0 and came out on [March 16, 2016](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx). Is this the utility you are asking about? Something else? Don't expect people to know what you are referring to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It might be just a bug on their webpage, but the release notes of said 3.4.0 version link to the 3.2.0 version though. And other than that date there is little "updates" on the whole site. Must not mean anything though.

Comment: Sorry that this is out of scope, and thank you for clearing up the issue.